# Read access violation (0xCCCCCCD0) when trying to display list

Tags: c, exception, linked-list

I'm storing to a list and then trying to display it, but when I call the display function I get this error. I'm not sure what the problem is as it isn't giving me any warnings or errors.

```
typedef struct {

    // Variables - Details on person taking survey
    int ppsNo;
    char firstName[15];
    char lastName[15];
    char address[30];
    char email[30];

    // Groups - Statistics are broken down based on these groups
    int age;
    int income;
    int gender;

    // Survey - What the survey questions will consist of
    int exercise;
    int alcohol;
    int cigarettes;

}survey_t; // Structure defined

struct list_el{

    survey_t data;
    struct list_el* next;
}; // List for passing values into the struct
```

Where I take in the values

```
void addSurvey(struct list_el** pointer) {

    struct list_el* data;
    data = (struct list_el*)malloc(sizeof(struct list_el));

    printf("\n===== Adding Someone to the Survey =====\n");

    // Depending on the number added, they output will be different
    // Taking in details and passing through the list
    printf("Enter PPS Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &data->data.ppsNo);
    printf("Enter First Name: ");
    scanf("%s", data->data.firstName);
    printf("Enter Last Name: ");
    scanf("%s", data->data.lastName);
    printf("Enter Address: ");
    scanf("%s", data->data.address);
    printf("Enter Email Address: ");
    scanf("%s", data->data.email);

    // Number added will determine the age group
    printf("\nEnter age group\n");
    printf("\t1: 18 - 20\n");
    printf("\t2: 20 - 30\n");
    printf("\t3: 30 - 50\n");
    printf("\t4: 50 - 65\n");
    printf("\t5: 65+\n");
    scanf("%d", &data->data.age);

    if (data->data.age > 5 && data->data.age < 1) {
        printf("Error - Re Enter Age group\n");
        scanf("%d", &data->data.age);
    }

    // Number added will determine income group
    printf("\nIncome Bracket - What category do you fall under\n");
    printf("\t1: No Income\n");
    printf("\t2: Less than 20,000\n");
    printf("\t3: Less than 40,000\n");
    printf("\t4: Less than 60,000\n");
    printf("\t5: Less than 80,000\n");
    printf("\t6: Less than 100,000\n");
    printf("\t7: Greater than 100,000\n");
    scanf("%d", &data->data.income);

    if (data->data.income > 7 && data->data.income < 1) {
        printf("Error - Re Enter Income\n");
        scanf("%d", &data->data.income);
    }

    // Number added will determine gender
    printf("\nGender\n");
    printf("\t1: Male\n");
    printf("\t2: Female\n");
    scanf("%d", &data->data.gender);

    if (data->data.gender > 2 && data->data.gender < 1) {
        printf("Error - Re Enter Gender\n");
        scanf("%d", &data->data.gender);
    }

    // Number will be added to determine how often they exercise
    printf("\nExercise - How often do you exercise\n");
    printf("\t1: Never\n");
    printf("\t2: Less than three times per week\n");
    printf("\t3: Less than five times per week\n");
    printf("\t4: More than five times per week\n");
    scanf("%d", &data->data.exercise);

    if (data->data.exercise > 4 && data->data.exercise < 1) {
        printf("Error - Re Enter Exercise\n");
        scanf("%d", &data->data.exercise);
    }

    // Number will be added to determine how many units they drink
    printf("\nAlcohol - How many units of Alcohol do you drink per week\n");
    printf("\t1: None\n");
    printf("\t2: Less than 2 Units per week\n");
    printf("\t3: Less than 3 Units per week\n");
    printf("\t4: More than 4 Units per week\n");
    scanf("%d", &data->data.alcohol);

    if (data->data.alcohol > 4 && data->data.alcohol < 1) {
        printf("Error - Re Enter Alcohol\n");
        scanf("%d", &data->data.alcohol);
    }


    // Number will be added to determine how many cigarattes per week they smoke
    printf("\nCigarettes - How many Cigarettes do you smoke per week\n");
    printf("\t1: None\n");
    printf("\t2: Less than 20 cigarettes per week\n");
    printf("\t3: Less than 40 cigarettes per week\n");
    printf("\t4: More than 40 cigarettes per week\n");
    scanf("%d", &data->data.alcohol);

    if (data->data.alcohol > 4 && data->data.alcohol < 1) {
        printf("Error - Re Enter Alcohol\n");
        scanf("%d", &data->data.alcohol);
    }

}
```

The function to display

```
void displayAll(struct list_el *pointer) {

    struct list_el *temp;
    temp = pointer;

    if (pointer == NULL) {
        printf("Nothing to Display");
    }

    else {
        while (temp != NULL) {
            printf("\nDisplaying All Surveys\n");
            printf("Name: %s %s", temp->data.firstName, temp->data.lastName);
            printf("\nPPS: %d", temp->data.ppsNo);
            printf("\nAddress: %s", temp->data.address);
            printf("\nAddress: %s", temp->data.email);

            // Switch statement that determines the age group depending on the value
            switch (temp->data.age) {
            case 1:
                printf("\n18 - 20");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\n20 - 30");
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\n30 - 50");
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\n50 - 65");
                break;

            case 5:
                printf("\n65+");
                break;
            }

            switch (temp->data.income) {

            case 1:
                printf("\nNo Income");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\nLess than 20,000");
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\nLess than 40,000");
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\nLess than 60,000");
                break;

            case 5:
                printf("\nLess than 80,000");
                break;

            case 6:
                printf("\nLess than 100,000");
                break;

            case 7:
                printf("\nGreater than 100,000");
                break;
            }

            switch (temp->data.age) {

            case 1:
                printf("\nMale");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\nFemale");
                break;
            }

            switch (temp->data.exercise) {

            case 1:
                printf("\t1: Never\n");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\nExercises less than three times per week");
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\nExercises less than five times per week");
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\n Exercises more than five times per week");
                break;
            }

            switch (temp->data.alcohol) {

            case 1:
                printf("\nNo Units\n");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\nLess than 2 Units per week");
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\nLess than 3 Units per week");
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\nMore than 4 Units per week");
                break;
            }

            switch (temp->data.cigarettes) {

            case 1:
                printf("\nNo Cigarettes");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\nLess than 20 cigarettes per week");
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\nLess than 40 cigarettes per week");
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\nMore than 40 cigarettes per week");
                break;
            }

            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

}
```

If anyone could explain what the error means too it would be greatly appreciated, for future use so I know how to deal with it in future.

Comment: Read access violation means you can't read that address (probably because it doesn't exist). The address looks like a debug sentinel value, i.e. something written to memory so as to be "obviously wrong" to assist debugging. I'll guess (without reading your code) that you have probably used memory after freeing it. In debug mode the memory manager will often overwrite freed memory with such sentinel values, but this is compiler and platform dependent, and you haven't mentioned your platform.

Comment: Debugger..................................

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialized pointer. In debug mode, the stack is usually filled with 0xCC values for faster error detection.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your is trying to access (read/write) memory at an illegal address. Typically this means that you dereference an illegal pointer value.

Your list seems incomplete.

In this code:

```
void addSurvey(struct list_el** pointer) {

    struct list_el* data;
    data = (struct list_el*)malloc(sizeof(struct list_el));
    ...
```

it seems you never use `pointer`. In other words, it seems you don't add the new element to the list. Are you missing something like:

```
*pointer = data;
```

Also you should initialize `next` of the new element, i.e.

```
data->next = NULL;
```